# Mass remove exif from pictures

Tags: bash, exif, exiftool

I have a folder with many directories that have pictures and I need to remove the EXIF file.

I used this code and it seems to work but my file size grow for no reason

```
find /Users/justinbarrilleaux/Downloads/2015 -type f -name '*.JPG' -exec exiftool -all= {} \;
```

Any clues how to solve this issue?

Comment: Since `exiftool` by default creates a backup of the original file, are you sure it is the edited files that grow?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure *each* file grew? Take a look inside your directory, I think there might be more files than before.

As far as I know, `exiftool` creates a backup for each modified picture. The backups are called `filename.JPG_original`.

Either delete the backups

```
rm /Users/justinbarrilleaux/Downloads/2015/*.JPG_backup
```

or prevent backups in the first place.

```
exiftool -overwrite_original -all= {}
```

Comment: Additional suggestion.  You are calling exiftool for each file and this is very slow. See [Exiftool Common Mistake 3](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/mistakes.html#M3).  Instead, run exiftool on the directory itself with `exiftool -overwrite_original -all= -ext jpg -r /Users/justinbarrilleaux/Downloads/2015`